# withCount() on relation hasMany

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use `withCount()` on a relationship of a relationship. The error I'm getting is `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::forums.threads does not exist.`.

Given these models:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function forums()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Forum');
    }
}

class Forum extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function threads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->orderByDesc('created_at');
    }
}
```

Consider the following in my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('forums')->withCount('forums.threads')->orderBy('order')->get();

    return view('home', compact('categories'));
}
```

And the following in my view:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->title }}<br>
        @foreach($category->forums as $forum)
            {{ $forum->title }}<br>
            {{ $forum->threads_count }}
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I know I can simply remove the `withCount` from the controller and use `$forum->threads->count()`, but is it possible to query counts the way I want?

If so, how? I'd like this to be as fast as possible by eager loading the counts (without loading all of the actual `threads`, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `withCount()` inside `closure`:

```
$categories = Category::with(['forums'=>function($q){
       $q->withCount('threads');
    }])->orderBy('order')->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

you dont need to load the threads you can use `$forum->threads()->count()`
It will return the count of thread without loading them

Comment: This adds an additional query to every single thread in the foreach loop.